# MapView android:clickable="false" not working?

Tags: android, android-mapview

While trying to make my map view unclickable, I use the XML approach `android:clickable="false"` as below

```
   <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraZoom="13"
    android:clickable="false"
    map:liteMode="true"
    map:mapType="normal" />
```

However, this is not working. It still is clickable and open up GoogleMap.

So I tried from the code instead

```
    MapView mapView = (MapView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    //... some other codes
    mapView.setClickable(false);
```

This is now good. It is no longer clickable. It looks strange to me that Java code works but not on the XML. Any clue why this happens, or I miss out anything on the XML?

Thanks!

Comment: Its like this with a few things,  such as focusable/focus can potentially act differently between xml and java.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine if you are using 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView' class

try this inside your `public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)`

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the clickable value in the parent layout of MapView.